# optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference don't fuse batchnorm layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have downloaded https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz example from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files and tried to convert it to optimized graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib

input_graph_path = './inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb'
output_optimized_graph_name = './model_optimized.pb'
input_node_names = ['input']
output_node_names = ['InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1']

input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open(input_graph_path, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)
    output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
            input_graph_def,
            input_node_names,
            output_node_names,
            tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

f = tf.gfile.FastGFile(output_optimized_graph_name, "w")
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Then using `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph` I have checked original graph and optimized graph, they are about the same:

Original:

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=input, type=float(1), shape=[1,299,299,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1, op=Reshape) 
Found 23853946 (23.85M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 control_edges
Op types used: 489 Const, 379 Identity, 188 Mul, 188 Add, 95 Conv2D, 94 Sub, 94 Rsqrt, 94 Relu, 15 ConcatV2, 10 AvgPool, 4 MaxPool, 2 Reshape, 1 BiasAdd, 1 Softmax, 1 Squeeze, 1 Placeholder
```

Optimized:

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=input, type=float(1), shape=None) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1, op=Reshape) 
Found 23853946 (23.85M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 control_edges
Op types used: 489 Const, 188 Mul, 188 Add, 95 Conv2D, 94 Sub, 94 Relu, 94 Rsqrt, 15 ConcatV2, 10 AvgPool, 4 MaxPool, 2 Reshape, 1 BiasAdd, 1 Softmax, 1 Squeeze, 1 Placeholder
```

Why input shape is dropped after convertion? is it possible to save the shape or to edit the graph to add shape after convertion (here is a note on BN folding https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference_lib.py#L28)?

Why batch norm are not fused in conv layers?
Looking at graph visualization using [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) I see these kind of ops that I suspect is BN.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Regarding BN seems only `BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization` and `FusedBatchNorm` are supported

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference_lib.py#L70